# FourSquare venue search using categories

Tags: foursquare

I am seeing some weird behaviors when I use the search API from FourSquare.  The site I am building lists all the nightclub spots (www.nationalvip.com)

When I search using 5 categories:

```
// 4bf58dd8d48988d121941735 - lounge
// 4bf58dd8d48988d11f941735 - nightclub
// 4bf58dd8d48988d1e7931735 - jazz club
// 4bf58dd8d48988d1e9931735 - rock club
// 4bf58dd8d48988d1d8941735 - gay clubs
```

Some of the nightclubs that are in category: 4bf58dd8d48988d1d8941735 do no show up.

So query like this:

```
/v2/venues/search?categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d121941735,4bf58dd8d48988d11f941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d8941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e9931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e7931735&ll=47.6097,-122.3331&radius=10000&intent=browse&v=20120801
```

Omits this venue:

```
https://foursquare.com/v/last-supper-club/40b13b00f964a520a7f61ee3
```

When I just use that category on it's own they do.

```
...?categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1d8941735&ll=47.6097,-122.3331&radius=10000&intent=browse&v=20120801
```

I have tried re-arranging the categories.  I'd really like to avoid having to call the API many times with various categories.

Has anyone else seen this happen?

Comment: correcting the LL attribute now.  The one I have posted in samples were not the right coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the location. The ll param you provided is for a location in San Francisco, but the venue you expect to appear is located in Seattle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I mistakenly did put the wrong code snippet.  I am actually using Seattle and getting other Seattle venues.  Here is the correct query: categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d121941735,4bf58dd8d48988d11f941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d8941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e9931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e7931735&ll=47.6097,-122.3331&radius=10000&intent=browse&v=20120801.

Comment: Looks like the problem with this query is that `4bf58dd8d48988d1d89‌​41735` is not a valid category ID. You can use the [API explorer](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3FcategoryId%3D4bf58dd8d48988d1d89%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B41735%26ll%3D47.6097,-122.3331%26radi%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bus%3D10000%26intent%3Dbrowse%26v%3D20120801) to test out your API calls, and inspect any errors.

Comment: I also noticed that there is a limit of 30 results...  if I get several categories some of the venues drop off "categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d121941735,4bf58dd8d48988d11f941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d8941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e9931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e7931735&ll=37.7854,-122.4084&radius=10000&intent=browse&v=20120801"  if I just get one "categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1d8941735&ll=47.6097,-122.3331&radius=10000&intent=browse&v=20120801" the venue "Last Supper Club" shows up.  Is there a way to get more than 30?

Comment: You can increate the `&limit=` parameter - up to a maximum of 50.

Answer (score 0):

you can increase limit upto 100
I have done that and radius upto 100000meters(100km)